# Highlight all other occurrences of hovered name

Tags: feature-request, comments

StackOverflow's comments are a great feature, as we all know. I was browsing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474419/link-styling-wont-apply-to-links-for-some-reason)'s comments and found myself looking for `@chrisgonzalez`' answer. It took me a couple of seconds to work out it had been deleted.

I'd like to propose some additional functionality for the `@[username]` syntax often used, to make following replies in comments easier:

- Hovering over an `@[username]` in a comment will highlight any previous comments in that thread made by the user. For example, hovering over `@bojangles` in comments would put a light yellow (or otherwise subtle highlight) on any of my previous comments (or perhaps my last one). This makes it much easier to *find* the referenced comment.
- If the previous comment was deleted (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474419/link-styling-wont-apply-to-links-for-some-reason) concerning the comment beginning with `@chrisgonzalez`, then there should be something notifying the user that the comment was deleted, like giving the hovered name a light red background, again keeping it quite subtle.

I'm not sure what to do with users who have changed their names, although this is understandably difficult to implement so is probably best left alone.

Comment: This seems easier to implement client side with a script?

Comment: A JavaScript implementation is assumed, primarily because that's the only way this can be done

Comment: [Well, actually…](http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/nqCxg) (Don’t do this)

Comment: (It’s interesting, too. Works great in Firefox; Chrome needs a click to get it going, but it works afterwards; and Opera doesn’t implement that at all.)

Comment: @minitech That's really quite neat, although it's a shame it's a bit quirky/not supported in some browsers (most notably IE9)